# How to dislay selected item on dropdown tree select with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, select, jsx, return-value, react-dropdown-tree-select

actually I'm using react dropdown tree select everything is working good but the problem is that when I select an item I can't get his value is the select box. it disappears. I want to keep dispalying after choosing it.
this is JSX code :

```
       <Row>
              <DropdownTreeSelect data={unitList}
                id='unit_id'
                mode='radioSelect'
                onChange={onChange}
                className="mdl-demo"

              />

            </Row>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

you need to update unitList accordingly to selected item in dropdown. There is 'checked' prop in each data node, and you need to keep it up to date.